# Interface builder not showing images to select for UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a couple of images in my Resources directory of my iphone project. I want to set one of those images for an UIImageView.

After adding the images to XCode project and correctly setting their targets to the project, Interface builder is not showing the images to select it in Attributes property of UIImage view. Do I have to refresh the Inspector? Am I missing some step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 3 then I think you have to save all changes and then close Interface Builder and re-open it in order for it to see those changes. Also I would highly recommend moving to Xcode 4 if you are not already using it.